# Default Filename SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, savefiledialog

I would like to create `SaveFileDialog` with `default file name` from value `DataGridViewCells`

So far I tried

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //first
    //mySaveFileDialog.FileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    //second
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFile.FileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    saveFile.ShowDialog();
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: You have two SaveFileDialog mySaveFileDialog (probably a component dropped on your form) and saveFile (built by program).

Comment: @RenaudBancelDAVEO i just use one when i run program...in this post i upoad 2 code for show i already try two of them

Comment: @GrantWinney winForms platform

Comment: nope...i already test it with "messagebox.show" it's have value....and when i try that with just simple string text like "test"...it's still not appear (i mean the "test", not dialog save box)

Answer (score 30):

The `SaveFileDialog` has a property intended for this purpose: [`DefaultFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog.defaultfilename%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) using Silverlight or [`FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) using .NET

Your (uncompilable) code from the question would become:

```
    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        SaveFileDialog mySaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        //Silverlight
        mySaveFileDialog.DefaultFileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
        //.NET
        mySaveFileDialog.FileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney - The link included in the answer shows otherwise.

Comment: @GrantWinney - I always forget that Silverlight exists... I'll adjust my answer to consider real platforms

Comment: @M.Babcock i can't fint "defaultFileName" property too..and yeah i use  WinForms platform

Comment: @katik - Can you describe what __failed__ means here? The property you show is the right one for Winforms so understanding what is happening is important.

Comment: @M.Babcock that 2 code i used above give no file name...just like that code not have any effect...i try to set it from property windows "mySaveFileDialog"...it's run well if i just use static string like 'test' default file name....but i kinda find hard when it's from variable

Comment: @katik - Where is `mySaveDialog` instantiated? It doesn't appear to be the same instance where you're setting the `Filename` property.

Comment: @katik the issue might be in the `indexing`, please see my answer.

Comment: I cannot see that property too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you need to use:

```
myDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
```

instead of

```
myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
```

Until you don't select 3 or more cells with mouse or whatsoever. You can index like `[2]`

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFile.FileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
    saveFile.ShowDialog();
}
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look the following way:

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFile.FileName = myDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
    saveFile.ShowDialog();
}
```

Use [FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) but set the filename before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try this in a simple WinForm application :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.FileName = "myfile.txt";
        saveFile.ShowDialog();
        string fileName = saveFile.FileName ;
        MessageBox.Show(fileName);
    }
```

It works!

Comment: .ShowDialog() should go after .FileName.

Answer (score -3):

to print all the controls in panel

```
public Bitmap MemoryImage;
    public void GetPrintArea( Panel pn1)
    {      
        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(panel13.Width, pn1.Height);
        pn1.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pn1.Width, pn1.Height));
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MemoryImage != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
    void printdoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {




        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - (this.panel13.Width / 2), this.panel13.Location.Y);


    }


        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(MemoryImage.Width, MemoryImage.Height);
        panel13.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel13.Bounds);

        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";

        bmp.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```