# Default file name for SaveFileDialog c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have few forms that export the grid data to excel, each time the form exports it calls the SaveFileDialog contol - for which I have a different form that remains the same for all the forms that need the SaveFileDialog, What I need to do is while saving the file, I want to display a default file name but it should be specific to the form not same for all the forms. I want to do that for C# windows application

Comment: Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Filename SaveFileDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199558/default-filename-savefiledialog)

Answer (score 3):

There is property called [`FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SaveFileDialog` which can be given for giving a default file name.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.FileName = "WhateverNameYouWant" //WithExtension
```