# Showing xlworkbook saving dialog while closing suggesting name

Tags: c#, excel, filenames, excel-interop, save-as

I have a project where in my program opens a excel file called Template.xlsx and makes some updates in it and then when i run this line of code

```
xlWorkBook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

I get the save as dialog box which is great but the problem is in the name field i get "Copy of Template.xlsx". I dont want that. I want to fill that field with for example "Order25.xlsx". is it possible?

Comment: ...you're asking how to save a workbook with a new name using VBA, is that right?

Comment: well its in c# my app opens a excel file which is the users template. and fills in the info and then when its done it closes the workbook using that line of code. i want to show the saving dialog box before closing and fill in custom name for the saving file.

Comment: You could try `xlWorkBook.SaveAs(*path*)`, although it would require you to know the path you're saving to, e.g. `xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\temp\Order25.xlsx")`

Comment: what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21199578/8112776

Comment: @SaeedAsgari, You can make it manually , but if you think it should make based on last book name in DB , you should last name and parse it's name and increase that number.

Comment: @Keyur in that case the path is already known and the dialog box would never be shown. its required that the user click on save by themselves. so we only want to set the filename but not the path.

Comment: @ashleedawg thats great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions in the comments, here is a possible solution using `SaveFileDialog` (you'll need `using System.Windows.Forms`):

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();  
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx";;  
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save the Excel File";
saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Order25.xlsx";

if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

I haven't tested it yet since I'm not near a computer, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah thats what i did. came back to right it down as answer but you already made an answer. so i mark it as solved. Thanks.